# JavaScript a method is called in onclick event in all of the buttons on the screen, even if the call onclick at a specified button is different

Tags: javascript, java, onclick

I have a caching problem on a button event in Java EE. In JSP, I call an inline JavaScript method in JSP page. This method requests a function in a Java class. Communication between the JSP and the method of java class occurs via structs. The problem is that after I modified this java class, all JSP screen links squeegee when the application calls the same JavaScript method. But this method is only called through a onClink() event is a screen button. Now all JSP buttons are calling this method, even if your event JavaScript onClink is calling another method. If the problem is not the call of JavaScript methods, how do I solve this problem? Refreshing this page does not.

An alternative would be to clear the cache only javascript. And keep the session java application and any other infromação of aplciação java web browser. The problem began to occur when I made an appointment in a java method using as parameter the "ApplicationForm" that takes the form data and use it as research. But for some reason this confunfoiu the browser

I do not want to sound ridiculous, but I can not put the code here.It is copyrighted and owned the company. But it is quite simple. Generic something would be.

JSP Page

The method includes call

```
// code jsp
<script>

incluirChamada function () {
// Calls the "javascript: incluirChamadaJava" java class via structs

}
```

the problem is that all the buttons call the incluirChamada () method. even if your onclink are specifying to another class

In the java code ...

```
javascript: incluirChamadaJava (ApplicationForm form) {

mehod slectUsingHibernate (Filter form) {

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks  user2953113. This generic code is this (edit)

Answer (score -1):

debug your code.  You problem have some function that is not closed properly.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Hi Joti Basi. I'am don't debug the jsp pages in eclipse